# CEPH Octupus: ceph command hangs. No data for prometheus also

Tags: ceph, cephfs

I'm facing an issue with ceph. I cannot run any ceph command. It literally hangs. I need to hit CTRL-C  to get this:

> ^CCluster connection interrupted or timed out

This is on Ubuntu 16.04. Also, I use Graphana with Prometheus to get information from the cluster, but now there is no data to graph. Any clue?

> cephadm version INFO:cephadm:Using recent ceph image ceph/ceph:v15
> ceph version 15.2.4 (7447c15c6ff58d7fce91843b705a268a1917325c) octopus
> (stable)

```
cephadm ls
[
    {
        "style": "cephadm:v1",
        "name": "mon.osswrkprbe001",
        "fsid": "56820176-ae5b-4e58-84a2-442b2fc03e6d",
        "systemd_unit": "ceph-56820176-ae5b-4e58-84a2-442b2fc03e6d@mon.osswrkprbe001",
        "enabled": true,
        "state": "running",
        "container_id": "afbe6ef76198bf05ec972e832077849d4a4438bd56f2e177aeb9b11146577baf",
        "container_image_name": "docker.io/ceph/ceph:v15.2.1",
        "container_image_id": "bc83a388465f0568dab4501fb7684398dca8b50ca12a342a57f21815721723c2",
        "version": "15.2.1",
        "started": "2020-10-19T19:03:16.759730",
        "created": "2020-09-04T23:30:30.250336",
        "deployed": "2020-09-04T23:48:20.956277",
        "configured": "2020-09-04T23:48:22.100283"
    },
    {
        "style": "cephadm:v1",
        "name": "mgr.osswrkprbe001",
        "fsid": "56820176-ae5b-4e58-84a2-442b2fc03e6d",
        "systemd_unit": "ceph-56820176-ae5b-4e58-84a2-442b2fc03e6d@mgr.osswrkprbe001",
        "enabled": true,
        "state": "running",
        "container_id": "1737b2cf46310025c0ae853c3b48400320fb35b0443f6ab3ef3d6cbb10f460d8",
        "container_image_name": "docker.io/ceph/ceph:v15.2.1",
        "container_image_id": "bc83a388465f0568dab4501fb7684398dca8b50ca12a342a57f21815721723c2",
        "version": "15.2.1",
        "started": "2020-10-19T20:43:38.329529",
        "created": "2020-09-04T23:30:31.110341",
        "deployed": "2020-09-04T23:47:41.604057",
        "configured": "2020-09-05T00:00:21.064246"
    }
]
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Would you mind closing your question since it's been answered on the ceph-users mailing list.

Comment: I have added an answer and marked it as correct. Is that enought? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been solved by rebooting MONs machines.